# Winform RDLC master/detail report display record on next page

Tags: c#, winforms, rdlc

I am building master/detail report using Visual Studio 2013, WinForm, Client Side (.rdlc) report and C#.

This is Sales Report where I show the Invoice Header and its related Invoice Details. The report looks like this:

[image]

Lets say the report shows 50 records over 10 pages. In this flow if a record (Invoice Header + Invoice Details) is displayed relatively towards the end the page and does not have enough space to fit on 1 page it will spill over to the next page. So I want to add a PAGE BREAK here so that the record (Invoice Header + Invoice Details) should completely move to the next page.

Is this possible?

I am trying to avoid a situation like this where some part is displayed on 1 page and some part get displayed on another page.

[image]

Comment: what does it mean "many a times a particular record (Invoice Header + Invoice Detail) is displayed towards the end of the page"? there must be a reason for that.

Comment: adjust page width in RDLC, select rdlc and goto Report-Report Property- lef,right,top,bottom

Comment: Senthil, I don't know how that will help. I do not intend to change the page dimensions here. I want to add a page break in case of a spill over.

Comment: I have found a link on YouTube which explains another way of creating master/detail reports - http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SE9_ZzjsLqs. Adding this for the benefit of others.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Edit:**

It looks like you're using a subreport. I'm not sure it's possible to obtain what you need using a subreport (it might be, I just don't know). If it's not a huge problem for you I think It's much easier to create a single datasource with your data and then use a `Tablix` grouping possibilities to sort, group and keep your groups together on a single page when possible. In order to do that you must select your `Row Groups` (both of them) and set `KeepTogether = True`

[image]

Check these reports that I created form your data, using the aforementioned method:

[A4 PDF Report](https://mega.co.nz/#!gdxUSABA!KPjaBjRxi0WsUFtGS3n5RiaHTR4sTLhX-qyI4TO3nLc)

[A5 XPS Report](https://mega.co.nz/#!0ZJDgABb!Z6v3RHpBRzxzKsLLgSYaRDq3Ww4qlhKTIE9nncasZ-o)

If this can be useful, I included a modified version of your project
[c# Project](https://mega.co.nz/#!hM5lnDZI!bHGGSGwJWfEOe63XzVGjrjbTcQcDYpfcXXUfXvKVtcc)

Comment: thanks for the reply. I tried many combinations but I am still struggling to get the desired result. What I have achieved so far is I am able to keep the detail part together i.e. the detail part does not spill over. But I am still not able to keep the master and detail part together exactly as shown in the above figure. Let me know if it comes back to you.

Comment: @YuviDagar I should see the .rldc definition to (maybe) help more, I don't know how you did managed to achieve that result.... what kind of objects are header and details? data repeater? grids?

Comment: Vland, please let me know, how should I send you the .rdlc file.

Comment: @YuviDagar You can upload a small winform project with your report and a set of sample data to mega.co.nz or something similar.

Comment: Vland please give me 2 to 3 days... I will create a small WinForm project, upload it on dropbox and send you the link.

Comment: @YuviDagar ok, I hope I can help you... Don't forget to include some test data

Comment: Vland, I have create a quick but working project with sample data. This is created using VS2013 using Framework 4. The data is included in List<T> so you can play around with it. Please download it from https://www.dropbox.com/s/1w3k83wnabzj7u8/MasterDetail.zip?n=185162187. Let me know if you need anything else. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @YuviDagar ok... it's pretty clear where the problem lies now. You have two different .rldc and are combining them in the same report. I don't think there's a way to keep them on the same page because they simply don't know about each other's position. I think you should merge them in ONE rldc definition. A grid with a repeating subgrid filtering by invoice nr. I'm on vacation but if you want in a few days I can take a look at it and try it myself.

Comment: Vland, thanks for the reply. I will try and work on your suggestion and let you know. If you get time can you also take a look at it after you are back from vacation. Have a great vacation !!!

Comment: @YuviDagar I found some time to play around, check the edited answer

Comment: Vland, thanks for the solution. I had a brief look and will spend more time on this and get back to you. If I have to do it this way, I will have to change my data source. Is there a way to add space between each record i.e. Header+Detail space Header+Detail.

Comment: yes of course, just add a bigger row at the end of the details section. you can do pretty much all the formatting you want. Plus, if you don't want to change your datasource, you can build a new one on the fly using LINQ and some custom Class you create just for the report.

Comment: Vland studied your code in detail and figured it out. Many thanks for all your help.