# Set rdlc report tablix to show record in one page

Tags: .net, sql-server, reporting-services, report, rdlc

I have a problem in RDLC report for displaying record in a page:

[image]

Comment: you want to repeat the header in each page?

Comment: @NandhakumarS, what is your question? You did not provide details to understand your issue.

Comment: Please visit below link. It may help you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20789726/winform-rdlc-master-detail-report-display-record-on-next-page